# How to set disableUISecurity property

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

I am trying to apply spring security to my web application. I am already familiar on the usage of the security:authorize tag for hiding UI elements in my jsp page. I read that starting from spring security 3.1.x you now have spring.security.disableUISecurity property to disable the security:authorize tag which will really help our testing. I tried searching google on how to set this property but I couldn't find a clear way on how to set this property. Does anyone know how to configure this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question over at spring forums and someone was able to help me. You just need to    add `-Dspring.security.disableUISecurity=true` as a jvm parameter

[Link to the post at spring](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/745781-how-to-configure-spring-security-disableuisecurity)

Comment: For more information, the code can be found there : `org.springframework.security.taglibs.TagLibConfig` in _spring-security-taglibs_